# Cordova calendar plugin add attendees

Tags: android, cordova, calendar, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a Cordova application (Android for now) that can send create calendar events. While going through Cordova documentation, I couldn't find a way to invite people/add attendees to the event via Cordova. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

```
function createCalendarEntry(){
                var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('apptTimeStart').value);
                var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('apptTimeEnds').value);
                var title = "Advisor appointment with Jane Doe";
                var eventlocation = document.getElementById('location').value;
                var notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
                var success = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
                var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
                window.plugins.calendar.createEventInteractively(title,eventlocation,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);
                //window.plugins.calendar.openCalendar();
        }
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Have you tried anything? Can you add some code so we have some context?

Comment: I'm using the basic cordova calendar plugin. Adding code to the question. @David

Comment: I'm also open to try any other plugin, if one's available. Or any other option too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/Calendar.java) of the plugin and there is no code related to adding attendees to an event. This makes sense as for adding an attendee you need the `EVENT_ID` ([AndroidDeveloper docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-attendees)) of the event you want to add the attendee to (which means you have to create an event before someone can attend).

As far as I know there is no plugin yet available for your use-case (at least I can not find one), which means if you would like to have that functionality you can fork the original plugin on github and implement the missing feature yourself. If you follow the AndroidDeveloper docs and just copy/rename/modify existing functions this should not be too hard.

*Note:*

You can use the `findEventWithOptions` method to get the `EVENT_ID` or you can modify the create method so it returns the `EVENT_ID` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks David for suggesting options! I too couldn't find anything in the docs around this. I'll see what I can do for this.